# combine duplicate records rows in sql into one row

Tags: sql-server-2014

I have duplicate records in one sql table . The rows has the same id but different values in different fields. how I can combine or merge those two rows or more into one row. Please help,

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group those rows on certain fields by specifying a [`GROUP BY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-be/library/ms177673.aspx) clause.

In your case you would group on the `ID` column. For the columns you select in the [`SELECT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-be/library/ms176104.aspx) clause that are not specified in the `GROUP BY` clause (i.e. columns other than `ID`), you will have to apply an [aggregate function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-be/library/ms173454.aspx) (e.g. `SUM`, `MAX`, `MIN`, ...).

**Edit** - Simplified example based on your image:

```sql
SELECT
    MasterID,
    CUSTNAME=MIN(CUSTNAME),
    ER1=MIN(ER1),
    ER1_BU=MIN(ER1_BU)
    -- For the other fields, the idea is the same
FROM
    your_table
GROUP BY
    MasterID
ORDER BY
    MasterID;
```

This example takes for each field the minimum of the fields for a particular `MasterID`. You did not really define what you mean by "merge". Perhaps you want the result to be a particular merge, you will have to clarify further if this example doesn't "merge" the rows like you want.

Comment: @Robert Example added

Comment: I want to those two rows to combine them together as shows in the photos into one row. in the same order. I will try this now

Comment: @Robert You will have to describe it in words rather than showing a picture to be absolutely clear as to what you want.